# Alternativas ao JSF para o front-end

Tags: java

Uma vez que eu queira manter o back-end em Java, o que eu poderia adotar para o front-end, em alternativa ao decadente JSF? Abraços!

Comment: A sua pergunta é totalmente baseada em opiniões, sendo assim, podendo haver várias. Já que é para front-end pode utilizar frameworks Javascript como Angular, React, Vue, etc... Outra alternativa é você utilizar frameworks front-end específicos para Java como Thymeleaf junto com Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar framework JS como React, Angular, Vue. Entretanto, você deve refatorar o seu backend para ser um servico.
Ex: Hoje com JSF você tem MBs (Managed Beans) que conversam os os xhtml. Se você refatorar o seu front para ser em angular, os MBs serão extintos e sua aplicação terá uma nova interface de entrada que são os endpoints REST.